# Does mongo replication split data or duplicate it

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, gridfs

I am creating a mongoDB/nodejs based CMS and I am using GridFS to store all the uploaded docs. The question I have is this:

> Does MongoDB replication sets allow increased amount of DB Storage, or
>   simply duplicates of the database. For Instance, if I have 5 servers
>   with 1TB of storage each, if I replica mongo across all of them, would
>   my GridFS system have theoretically 5TB of storage (minus caching and
>   padding) or 1TB of storage duplicated several times for better read
>   performance?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Informal description:

Replication = The same copy of the data on multiple nodes, i.e., 5 nodes with 1TB each provide 1TB overall.

Sharding / Partitioning = Fraction of the data goes to the nodes, i.e., 5 nodes with 1TB each provide 5TB overall.

Each approach has certain advantages and disadvantages, e.g., replication can help with read throughput and is good as backup, but slows down inserts (depending on commit level), whereas partitioning can help with insert throughput and distributed lookups.
Again, details left to the storage system implementor.

Answer (score 2):

`Sharding` means splitting your data across multiple nodes, this is useful when you have a huge amount of data.

`Replication` means copying the data from a node to another node, and it's useful when your application is read heavy or you want to backup your data for example.

Resources:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sharding 
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Replication 
http://nosql-exp.blogspot.com/2010/09/mongodb-sharding-and-replication-with.html

Answer (score 1):

> Does MongoDB replication sets allow increased amount of DB Storage, or
>   simply duplicates of the database.

Mongo can do both.

The first case is called [`sharding`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sharding).

The second case is called [`replication`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Replication).